# How can I output a list of DOM elements that starts from an ID element given by a user?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-lists, prompt

There is a JS function that gives me a list of DOM tree and I need to let user enter Id that will be the first on output list, no DOM objects from the list before it should be printed. I don't really get how to do this.

I wanted to take the Id (div1/image1/parag1...) from prompt and than use it as an argument, but I don't know how to realize it in code.

```js
function DOMTree(e, ul = document.getElementById('tree')) {
  for (let i = 0; i < e.childNodes.length - 1; i++) {
    if (e.childNodes[i].id != 'tree') {
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      let el = e.childNodes[i];

      if (e.childNodes[i].id != undefined) {
        li.innerText = e.childNodes[i].nodeName + ' ' + e.childNodes[i].id;
        ul.append(li);
      }

      let ul1 = document.createElement('ul');
      DOMTree(e.childNodes[i], ul1);
      ul.append(ul1);
    }
  }
}

function buttonF() {
  DOMTree(document.body);
  var input = prompt("From which element do you want to show DOM?");
  document.getElementById(input);

  input = document.getElementById();
  document.getElementById(input)
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="div1">
    <h2 id="header1">
      Simple text, nothing special.
    </h2>

    <p id="parag1"> Тext of parag1.</p>

    <img id="image1" src='img/cactus.png' width="150"><br>
  </div>

  <div id="div2">
    <h2 id="header2">Still same text.</h2>

    <p id="parag2">Text of parag2.</p>

    <img id="image2" src="img/sunflower.png" width="150"> <br>
  </div>

  <ul id="idList"></ul>

  <button id="button1" onclick="buttonF()">Show the DOM tree:</button><br><br>
  <script src="jscode.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how to use this site. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it.

First, you will want to get the input from the prompt which you did. Then pass that in getElementById as the first argument, then the destination as the second.

```
function buttonF(){
  var input = prompt("From which element do you want to show DOM?");
  DOMTree(document.getElementById(input),document.querySelector("#idList"));
}
```

```js
function DOMTree(e, ul = document.getElementById('tree')) {
  for (let i = 0; i < e.childNodes.length - 1; i++) {
    if (e.childNodes[i].id != 'tree') {
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      let el = e.childNodes[i];
      if (e.childNodes[i].id != undefined) {
        li.innerText = e.childNodes[i].nodeName + ' ' + e.childNodes[i].id;
        ul.append(li);
      }
      let ul1 = document.createElement('ul');
      DOMTree(e.childNodes[i], ul1);
      ul.append(ul1);
    }
  }
}

function buttonF(){
  var input = prompt("From which element do you want to show DOM?").replace("#","");
  DOMTree(document.getElementById(input),document.querySelector("#idList"));
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
        <h2 id="header1">
            Simple text, nothing special.
        </h2>

        <p id="parag1"> Тext of parag1.</p>

        <img id="image1" src = 'img/cactus.png' width="150"><br>

        </div>

        <div id="div2">
        <h2 id="header2"> 
            Still same text. 
        </h2>

        <p id="parag2">Text of parag2.</p>

        <img id="image2" src ="img/sunflower.png" width="150"> <br>

        </div>

    <ul id="idList"></ul>
    

    <button id = "button1" onclick = "buttonF()">Show the DOM tree:</button><br><br>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @isherwood, I didn't validate the input. I made a change to remove the # in the input ID in case that was added. I could have added some validation but should point OP in the correct direction.

Comment: What's the point of the snippet, then?